# CSS Expand div width to match other float

Tags: html, css

Goodday,

I got 2 divs i have 1 floated right and 1 floated left.

the float right has width: 200px;
and the parent is width: 1000px;
How can i say that the float left is 1000 - 200 = 800 so the div always fills the width?

The width of div float right is dynamic so procentual width does not work.

[image]

here an image that explains

Comment: Please show what you have done,.

Comment: http://s29.postimg.org/6nmggqip3/Naamloos.png Image explainin

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/A8zLY/49/)**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="right"></div>
    <div class="left"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.container {
    width:600px;
    height:200px;
    border:1px solid;
}
.left {
    width:auto;
    height:200px;
    background:red;
    overflow:hidden;
}
.right {
    height:200px;
    width:200px;
    background:blue;
    float:right;
}
```

Comment: Glad to have helped you :)

Answer (score 2):

try this code   [demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vsIem)

```
<aside class="panel">
    ...
</aside>
<div class="content">
    ...
</div>

.content {
    overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px  solid;
}
.panel {
    float: right;
    width: 200px;
  border: 1px  solid;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4dgaurav/A8zLY/51/)**

use `calc`

css

```
.container {
    width:1000px;
    height:200px;
}
.left {
    width:calc(100% - 200px); /* this will take the remaining space */
    height:200px;
    background:red;
}
.right {
    height:200px;
    width:200px;
    background:blue;
    float:right;
}
```

Comment: As OP clearly mentioned `The width of div float right is dynamic so procentual width does not work.`

Answer (score 1):

You can use percentage, after you set parent div a 1000px of width;

```
<div class="parentDiv clearfix">
   <div class="floatRight"></div>
   <div class="floatLeft"></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.parentDiv{
   width:1000px;
   height:300px;
   border:1px solid black;}
.floatRight{
   height:300px;
   width:20%;
   background-color:red;
   float:right;
}
.floatLeft{
   height:300px;
   width:80%;
   background-color:yellow;
   float:left;
}
```

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6JqY7/)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

It should be like that. [JSFiddle is here](http://jsfiddle.net/yWxC8/)

**HTML**

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="right"></div>
    <div class="left"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.parent {
    width: 1000px;
}
.left {
    overflow: hidden;
}
.right {
    float: right;
    width: 200px;
}
```